# Javascript Time Calculator Correction

Tags: javascript, html, time, calculator, modulus

Currently My code tells the time and can take on offset for hours on a 24 hour scale, my issue is it does not allow me to change the code in offset of + 30 minutes which I would like the ability to do. My if statements aren't getting me the outcome I want so I started to redesign my code using modulo to help but can't find away to make my html and the new code using modulo to coordinate. Thanks.

HTML Code:

```js
function startTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  var h = d.getUTCHours();
  var m = d.getUTCMinutes();
  var s = d.getUTCSeconds();
  h = checkHour(h);
  m = checkMinute(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt3').innerHTML = "" + checkHour(h - 5) + ":" + checkMinute(m + 30) + ":" + s;
  document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = +checkHour(h + 2) + ":" + m + "";
  document.getElementById('txt2').innerHTML = +h + ":" + m + "";
  document.getElementById('txt4').innerHTML = "" + checkHour(h + 8) + ":" + m + "";
  document.getElementById('txt5').innerHTML = "0" + checkHour(h - 10) + ":" + m + "";
}

function checkTime(i) {
  var j = i;
  if (i < 10) {
    j = "0" + i;
  }
  return j;
}

function checkHour(i) {
  var j = i;

  if (i > 23) {
    j = j - 24;
  }
  if (i < 0) {
    j = "0" + i;
  }
  return j;
}

function checkMinute(i) {
  var j = i;
  if (i > 59) {
    j = j + 30;
  }
  if (i < 0) {
    j = "0" + i;
  }
  return j;
}

setInterval(function() {
  startTime();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<font color="white" face="Montserrat">
  <span style="font-size:110px; border: 4px solid crimson; position:absolute; left:25px; top:440px;" id="txt1"></span>
</font>

<font color="white" face="Montserrat">
  <span style="font-size:110px; border: 4px solid crimson; position: absolute; left:475px; top:440px;" id="txt3"></span>
</font>

<font color="white" face="Montserrat">
  <span style="font-size:110px; border: 4px solid crimson; position: absolute; left:225px; top:540px;" id="txt2"></span>
</font>

<font color="white" face="Montserrat">
  <span style="font-size:110px; border: 4px solid crimson; position:absolute; left:870px; top:540px;" id="txt4"></span>
</font>

<font color="white" face="Montserrat">
  <span style="font-size:110px; border: 4px solid crimson; position:absolute; left:1075px; top:440px" id="txt5"></span>
</font>
```

Javascript using modulo which I might substitute for my current code for time:

```
/* var date = new Date(null);
date.setSeconds(timeInSeconds);

// retrieve time ignoring the browser timezone - returns hh:mm:ss
var utc = date.toUTCString();
// negative start index in substr does not work in IE 8 and earlier
var time = utc.substr(utc.indexOf(':') - 2, 8)

// retrieve each value individually - returns h:m:s
var time = date.getUTCHours() + ':' + date.getUTCMinutes() + ':' +  date.getUTCSeconds();

// does not work in IE8 and below - returns hh:mm:ss
var time = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);

// not recommended - only if seconds number includes timezone difference
var time = date.toTimeString().substr(0, 8); */

console.log(display(60 * 60 * 2.5 + 25)) // 2.5 hours + 25 seconds

function display (seconds) {
  const format = val => `0${Math.floor(val)}`.slice(-2)
  const hours = seconds / 3600
  const minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60

  return [hours, minutes, seconds % 60].map(format).join(':')
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the code is supposed to do -- it might be because you have white text on a white background.... BTW the `font` element was deprecated many years ago in favor of using CSS.